# What is a good word for people who demand and take things just because they want it?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking for a an adjective, preferably in English, to describe some people who do certain things, which I will explain with real life examples. I am using it in a non-fiction book. I am writing this in words obviously, but I want the word or phrase to be able to depict the severity of this type of action or personality so the reader of my book can really feel the emotions. If words are one dimensional, then movies (with visuals, sounds and actions) are three dimensional. People watching a movie can build a relationship with characters and really 'feel' for them, be empathetic and experience emotions. I would like a word or phrase to be able to do that in the following examples. I am writing a book in English but I guess if there are words in other languages I could say "John Doe is a really --- person/he is really ---, as the [other nationality where the word is borrowed from] would say.", like "John Doe is really *XYZ*, as the Martians would say."

**Example 1:**
Please refer to [this news article](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/womans-fury-bride-sneaks-garden-14444961). In this news article, a bride stole some rare flowers from a woman who grew them in her garden, for her wedding. The gardener took years to track down the flowers, and the bride got off with a small fine for trespassing rather than stealing, and simply replied to the owner, "They're just flowers. I needed flowers for my wedding and you have a whole yard full."
If I use some imagination and play this scene in my head, I could imagine the bride nonchalantly saying it with a shrug of her shoulder as if it is not a big deal and not caring about the damage caused to others as long as she got what she wanted.

**Example 2:**
This happened to my mother personally so I don't have a reference. My father's brother took something valuable of my mother's when he was visiting and when she discovered it was missing, she asked him if he knew where it was and he just nonchalantly and matter-of-factly replied, like in example 1 above, he wanted it so he took it. He did it again with my sister when she was a little kid, taking her clothes without telling my mother, to give to his own daughter.

**Example 3:**
This happened to my mother personally as well so I don't have a reference. Same perpertrator - my father's brother demanded money (asked for outright, not simply borrow) from my mother once to buy a house. My mother was a single parent with only a part time job and had university fees and our mortgage to pay. He just boldly asked for it and when my told him (normally, not in any special tone) that she had none, but could lend him a some when she gets her next pay check, but definitely nothing enough to buy a house with, he got offended, sniffed with contempt and said "You won't give me any? I'll ask my brother for it!"

**What I would like:**
I am looking for a word, an adjective or adjective phrase to describe the type of people in each of the examples, specifically, their act of just taking what they want and making that active and purposeful decision to do this damage and not even care about it, as opposed to say, taking something without paying because you thought it was free, or didn't know it belonged to someone. It must have a negative connotation, (eg, 'bold', 'brave' are not good here). As I have personally experienced examples 2 and 3, I can empathise with the gardener in example 1. I would like the word to hopefully embody the personality of and create an impression for the reader, what the perpetrator is like (so that I may build on this later in the book and readers can understand "XYZ is/is not something John Doe would do because he is a --- person").

---

I have thought of **despicable** but not sure if it is strong enough, seeing as though it is used in the kid's movie, *"Despicable Me"* and somewhat lightens the mood/severity of it.

I have also thought of **entitled** - this is a good one but I need more because I have a fourth example where the perpetrators used lies to get what they wanted (rather than stealing) but then boldly showed off their accomplishments/what they obtained (effectively rubbing salt into the victim's wounds). Entitled would not work here.

Thank you and sorry for the long explanation.

Comment: MOD NOTE: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Answer (score 2):

"Entitled" is the word you are looking for.

> **Entitled** (adjective): feeling that you have the right to do or have what you want without having to work for it or deserve it, just because of who you are.
>
> Example: These kids are spoiled, entitled, self-absorbed, and apathetic.

[Cambridge English Dictionary]

Answer (score 2):

How about the word "avaricious"? I also like the word "rapacious" for this purpose. Honestly, "predatory" also fits the bill. Maybe you could call this "narcisisstic predation"? That captures the personality pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

These actions can be described as those of a [selfish](https://www.lexico.com/definition/selfish) person. The online dictionary Lexico defines this as

> (of a person, action, or motive) lacking consideration for other people; concerned chiefly with one's own personal profit or pleasure.

There are several close synonyms for *selfish* such as **egotistical**, **self-serving**, **self-regarding** and so on. A long list can be found on [thesarus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/selfish)

However in extreme cases it can be a characteristic of [narcissism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism) which is a recognised personality disorder. That's not to say that your uncle has a narcissistic personality but he certainly seems to have an exaggerated sense of his own worth.

Comment: Not my brother, my father's brother. Thanks for the list of words.

Comment: @StephanieChen-Xu I realised that when I looked at your question again. I've changed it to "uncle"

Comment: Grasping? Brass-necked? The latter means shameless but also conveys feelings of feelingless impudence.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to my own question in case it is beneficial to other people.

I thought of the word "*audacious*", [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/audacious) defines it as:
"showing a willingness to take risks or offend people".

Comment: Audacious might work but it usually has positive rather than negative connotations. Crimes are sometimes called audacious but that is because the reporter recognises something positive in the style of the action even though the intent is criminal. The incidents in your examples seem to be rather more mean-spirited than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use acquisitive or acquisitiveness?
Acquisitive: excessively interested in acquiring money or material things.

Comment: I feel like "acquisitive" is more for people who are interested in acquiring things and therefore actively go seek them out, like a company acquiring another, whereas I am thinking of people who sees something that is not theirs, want it, and take it, and justify taking it with simply their desire to have it. Anyone have comments on usage of this word?

Comment: I've just seen Jenna's answer. Rapacious is better than acquisitive.